# querying nested objects with random names - lodash/javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

need to get parent of objects where matching child is found..

```
Obj = 
{
  trees:{
    small:[1,2,3],
    medium:[4,5,13],
    large:[1,2,10]
  },
  plants:{
    small1:[11,12,3],
    medium1:[14,15,3],
    large1:[11,12,10]
  }
}
```

expected retulsts of querying 3's sud be

```
{
 trees:{
    small:[1,2,3]
  },
  plants:{
    small1:[11,12,3],
    medium1:[14,15,3]
  }
}
```

So what I have tried is to

```
function findInObjectsOfObjects(obj) {
            console.log(obj)
            for (var i in obj) {
                console.log(obj[i])
                if (typeof(obj[i]) == "object" && obj[i].length < 1)
                    findInObjectsOfObjects(obj[i])
                else {
                    return obj[i]; -- but loop breaks here
                }
            }
        }
```

I was trying to match values

```
for (var obj1 in obj) {
   findInObjectsOfObjects(obj1).indexOf(3) // instead will be using indexOf
}
```

but it just returns 1st array and breaks at the return. The problem is it can be any deep in nests.

Comment: is `obj` an array or an object?

Comment: Its an object...corrected...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by checking the value and a cascading return of the inner objects.

```js
function find(object, value) {
    var result;
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var found;
        if (Array.isArray(object[k]) && object[k].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            result = result || {};
            result[k] = object[k];
            return;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            found = find(object[k], value);
            if (found) {
                result = result || {};
                result[k] = found;
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var object = { trees: { small: [1, 2, 3], medium: [4, 5, 13], large: [1, 2, 10] }, plants: { small1: [11, 12, 3], medium1: [14, 15, 3], large1: [11, 12, 10] } },
    result = find(object, 3);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```